# JTA-Transactions - Mismatch between Spring and Hibernate connection release?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jta, atomikos

Versions in use:
Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.3.10.Final, Atomikos 3.9.26

We are in the process of upgrading our main webapp to Hibernate 4. We mainly use `HibernateTemplate` and `JdbcTemplate` for access to multiple databases (DB2 and Oracle) with Atomikos as JTA-TransactionManager.

**The problem:** While using only `HibernateTemplate` or only `JdbcTemplate`s in a single transaction works fine, using `JdbcTemplate` and `HibernateTemplate` together in one transaction causes `StaleStateException`s in certain cases.

Here is an example where the problem occurs - the code is wrapped in a `TransactionalProxyFactoryBean` with `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED`:

```
public class MyServiceImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements MyService {

  private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyServiceImpl.class);

  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Override
  public void execute() {
    // save new entity instance with HibernateTemplate
    MyEntity e = new MyEntity();
    e.setMyProperty("first value");
    getHibernateTemplate().save(e);

    // use JdbcTemplate to access DB
    String sql = "select * from my_table";
    getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new RowCallbackHandler() {
        @Override
        public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
             // process rows
            }
         });

     // update entity instance with HibernateTemplate
     e.setMyProperty("second value");
     getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(e);

     // make sure the flush occurs immediately. This is needed in to demonstrate the problem. (Otherwise the property UPDATE would be cached and issued on commit, just after Spring closed the connection used for the JdbcTemplate and the problem would not show)
     getHibernateTemplate().flush();
  }

  public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
    return jdbcTemplate;
  }

  public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
  }
}
```

**Our conclusions:** The exception is basically caused by different ways `HibernateTemplate` and `JdbcTemplate` accquire and release the database connection.

The `HibernateTemplate` directly delegates to Hibernate which uses the connection release mode AFTER_STATEMENT (set by Spring if a `JtaTransactionManager` is provided). This causes Hibernate to get a connection from the Atomikos connection pool, perform the SQL and close its connection which doesn't close the physical connection but returns it to the connection pool.

The `JdbcTemplate` uses Spring's `DataSourceUtils.getConnection(...)` to get a connection from the Atomikos connection pool, performs the SQL and calls `DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(...)` which itself doesn't call `Connection.close()`. The connection isn't closed by Spring in `DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(...)` (and in consequence not returned to the connection pool) but bound to the thread for reuse in `DataSourceUtils.getConnection(...)`.

So it seems as if in a JTA context, Spring teaches Hibernate to use connection release mode AFTER_STATEMENT (which is also recommeded by Hibernate for JTA) but behaves totally different in it's `DataSourceUtils`.

In detail, we tracked down the cause like following:

1. The `StaleStateException` is thrown because the UPDATE-Statement for setting "second value" at the entity does not affect any row in the database.
2. This is because the UPDATE-Statement happens on another connection than the INSERT-Statement.
3. This is because the original connection used by the INSERT-Statement is still considered in use by the connection pool.
4. This is because close() is never called on the first connection after it was used for the `JdbcTemplate`.
5. This is because `DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(...)` which is called by the `JdbcTemplate` when finished doesn't call `Connection.close()` in a JTA-Transaction-Context.

Things we tried and failed at:

1. Make Hibernate use AFTER_TRANSACTION or ON_CLOSE as connection release mode - prevented by Spring as `SpringJtaSessionContext` with it's AFTER_STATEMENT is hardcoded.
2. Configure Spring close the DB connection on connection release.

What are we doing wrong?
Any configuration we forgot?
Is it a Spring/Hibernate problem at all or should the Atomikos connection pool behave differently by not waiting for a call to `Connection.close()` before making the connection available again?

Thanks a lot for your help!

**Spring context for Hibernate and JTA configuration:**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>

    <property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- Stripped down configuration for the toy project to reproduce the problem -->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.company.DB2Dialect</prop>

            <!-- hibernate.transaction.factory_class and hibernate.transaction.jta.platform are implicitly set by setting the jtaTransactionManager property -->

            <!-- Properties wie normally use in production
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.company.DB2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_outer_join">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</prop> -->
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:**/*.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.IsolationLevelDataSourceRouter"
    scope="singleton">
    <property name="targetDataSources">
        <map>
            <entry key="ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/wawi_rr" />
            <entry key="ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/wawi_ru" />
            <entry key="ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/wawi_rc" />
            <entry key="ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/wawi_s" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/wawi" />
</bean>


<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManagerName">
        <value>java:comp/env/TransactionManager</value>
    </property>
    <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Spring context for Service configuration:**

```
<bean id="myService" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target">
        <ref bean="myServiceTarget" />
    </property>
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="transactionManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myServiceTarget" class="org.example.MyServiceImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="myMBean" class="org.example.MyMBean">
    <property name="myService" ref="myService" />
</bean>
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:205)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:308)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.flush(HibernateTemplate.java:837)
    at org.example.MyServiceImpl.execute(MyServiceImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.example.MyMBean.execute(MyMBean.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1245)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1239)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.SpringModelMBean.invoke(SpringModelMBean.java:90)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3281)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3183)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate$27.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:840)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:340)
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: I do not see anything related to managing transactions, so I highly doubt that you actually have a proper tx setup.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that the code is wrapped in TransactionProxyFactoryBean with PROPAGATION_REQUIRED - So the tx should be set up. I edited the question to mention it.

Comment: Why on earth are you still using the `TransactionProxyFactoryBean`? That is old, well ancient actually. There are better ways. Are you sure you are using the transactional proxy and not the unproxied target of the `TransactionProxyFactoryBean`? The exception you get makes me think that, can you add the stack trace?

Comment: I added the stacktrace and some more class and spring configuration context. - Regarding TransactionProxyFactoryBean: Is it the most elegant way? Not at all. - Would I use it on a new project? Certainly not. - Is it still valid for brownfield projects? Yes, according to [Spring reference - Box Where is TransactionProxyFactoryBean?](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative)

Comment: Still if you can refactor to something better, saves you xml and headaches. I would at least make the target an inner bean so that you cannot mistakenly get the wrong service. Before executing the select I believe you should flush, this is also what hibernate does before issuing a select query. I would suspect that this works if you used hibernate to execute the plain sql query instead of a `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: did you enable optimisticLocking ?

Comment: @M.Deinum - Thanks for your efforts in sorting this out! Removing `JdbcTemplate` and executing sql via Hibernate works as mentioned in the question. Combining `JdbcTemplate` and hibernate calls leads to the problem - with or without manual flushing in between. Maybe removing `JdbcTemplate`s is the way to go but if I understood correctly, combining `JdbcTemplate` and hibernate queries should work together in Spring.